# How to find missing alpha values in sets of data within same table in SQL

Tags: sql, search, scripting

I have a table of many values where one column has the WO Number, and another column has the Resource ID.  I need to be able to find all the WO numbers that do not have a resource value of "RW".

Here is an example of the typical information.  I need to be able to know that work order 5678 does not have an "RW" Resource ID.

**WO Number - Resource ID**
1234 - IN
1234 - WE
1234 - AS
1234 - RW
5678 - PR
5678 - WE
5678 - IN
5678 - AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT M1.WONumber
FROM Mytable M1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 --or NULL, 1, *, 'bob'. All the same
                  FROM Mytable M2
                  WHERE M2.ResourceID = 'RW' AND M1.WONumber = M2.WONumber)
```

Comment: If M2.ResourceID is null would this adversly effect the results?

Comment: @Gary B2312321321: yes. We are only *not* looking for M2.ResourceID = 'RW'. So if it's NULL or 'WE' there are no rows for that WONumber  in the NOT EXISTS correlation -> WOnumber has no 'RW' ResourceID

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the WO numbers with 'RW' from the set of all WO numbers:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wo_number FROM mytable
MINUS
SELECT DISTINCT wo_number FROM mytable WHERE resource_id = 'RW'
```

Should work.  I'm not an SQL power-user however, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Not all database systems support the MINUS keyword, off hand for example SQL Server doesn't

Comment: I attack every problem in life with a Venn diagram.  Could explain why dating was so difficult in college.

Answer (score 0):

IF you know the number of possible resources and each WO Number can have at most 1 of each possible resource, then simply search for those WO Numbers that don't have all possible resources:

```
SELECT WO_Number 
FROM <table> 
GROUP BY WO_Number 
HAVING COUNT(*) <> (number of resources)
```